# How to solve " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException"

Tags: java, java-15

How to solve " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException" When I run the same code with Java 15, at runtime I get errors indicating that

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
    at com.hibernatedemo.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

I added the pom.xml but it didn't work

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Better if you can provide the complete exception trace you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and built the "jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar" file separately and my problem was solved. Thank you very much, and also there is related to "pom.xml".

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If anyone else encounters this problem, they can download the file from here.
[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar)